# Setting text of controls on form dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a WinForms app that I am currently implementing a translation engine in. What I have so far is a bunch of text documents that follow the syntax like:

```
messages.manualupdate="There is a manual update available for ProgName.\n\nDo you want to update to version {0}.{1}.{2}{3}?"
messages.errorcopy="Clicking OK will copy the error so you can paste it elsewhere!"
messages.error="Error"
messages.notsupported.title="Unsupported client"
messages.notsupported.message="This version is no long supported. Please wait for an update."
```

I have lots of these for different languages, for example:

```
messages.manualupdate="é disponibile un'aggiornamento manuale del programma ProgName.\n\nVuoi aggiornare alla versione {0}.{1}.{2}{3}?"
messages.errorcopy="Cliccando OK eseguirete una copia degli errori visualizzati"
messages.error="Error"
messages.notsupported.title="Client non supportato"
messages.notsupported.message="Questa versione non è utilizzabile al momento. attendi il prossimo aggiornamento!"
```

I then parse this into a `DynamicObject` which I can access like `language.messages.notsupported.error`. What I would like to know is if I can somehow link all the controls on the form to use variables from the dynamic object on creation. For instance I have a button on my form that I want to have the text "Error" in. Before the form shows, I set the `language` variable to the users chosen language, and then when the form shows it simply loads the text from `language`. Is there a way to do this in the designer rather than having to write a method that is called in the Forms constructor as it seems to me like a little bit of a waste to set all the button text to a value and then change them all when the form loads. I'm looking for a sort of binding, but to the controls Text parameter.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has a walkthrough on string localization that might be of use to you [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the approach you are trying to avoid looks best to me. I will suggest you to create a property for the control where you are trying to set the Text. In Set attribute, check for the language selected and get the appropriate text for you.

```
public string Error
{
    set { _errorLabel.Text = value; }
}

private void SetText()
{
    if(EnglishSelected)
        Error = "English";
}
```

Regarding waste of time, well, I will just suggest not to set anything in designer and directly set the property in Load form. But I would like to add one more point here that any of the approach will not hit your application speed. First its about making your application expandable and maintainable and then about making it fast. Setting logical things in designer is always a bad practice. If your application is not tiny/small then I will suggest you to follow some design patterns like [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) and move all this logical things in Presenter. Not trying to preach but just suggesting.

And yes, in our company one of team is working in localization part of the application. Using resource may be a better way of doing this.

Hope it helps.